# Should we merge esri-silverlight and arcgis-silverlight-api tags into arcgis-silverlight?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There appears to be no difference between the [esri-silverlight](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esri-silverlight) and [arcgis-silverlight-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-silverlight-api) tags.

The latter has an **[ArcGIS API for Silverlight community page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/silverlight-api/)** available for it and even the top Google hits on "esri silverlight" lead there.

There is also a CodePlex project called **[ArcGIS Silverlight Toolkit](http://esrisilverlight.codeplex.com/)**.

Should we therefore make [esri-silverlight](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esri-silverlight) a synonym of [arcgis-silverlight-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-silverlight-api) (as master)?

Comment: I liked how quickly @mattwilkie approach achieved consensus and implementation so thought I would try that style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vote up this answer if you prefer [arcgis-silverlight-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-silverlight-api) as master

Answer (score 2):

My personal opinion as a developer trying to make sense of the *many* products under the ArcGIS brand would be to have tags specific to each product, toolkit, or API, so that everyone is clear what the question is really about and queries about those specific products can be found more readily and with less unrelated cruft.

Therefore, we would have separate tags for [arcgis-silverlight-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-silverlight-api), [arcgis-silverlight-viewer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-silverlight-viewer), and [arcgis-silverlight-toolkit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-silverlight-toolkit), **should there actually be any questions about those specific products** (I wouldn't suggest creating tags for nonexistent questions, and to limit retagging efforts to only when other edits are required).

This is actually the approach that the community has tended to follow over the years, so I would anticipate it being the easiest to implement.

I agree that the [esri-silverlight](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esri-silverlight) tag is pretty useless. Even worse is [esri-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esri-api) (see [related discussion](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3324/753)).

Answer (score 1):

Vote up this answer if you prefer [esri-silverlight](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esri-silverlight) as master

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, a new tag of [arcgis-silverlight](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-silverlight) to cover the **[ArcGIS API for Silverlight](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/silverlight-api/)**, the **[ArcGIS Silverlight Toolkit](http://esrisilverlight.codeplex.com/)** AND the **[ArcGIS Viewer for Silverlight](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/silverlight-viewer/)** i.e. create this new tag then make the existing two tags synonyms of it.