# Do we need a [esri-api] tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, burninate

Currently there are 29 questions tagged with [esri-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esri-api).

IMHO, this is a very totally useless tag, since there is nothing called the esri-api. There are several different APIS for different [arcgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis) and [esri](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esri) products, and tagging something with [esri-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esri-api) does not lead to any specific insight.

Should the tag be burninated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree wholeheartedly, [esri-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esri-api) must be burninated.

I'll just link to this related answer: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3328/753

Basically I would propose that we encourage people to use tags specific to each product, application, API or toolkit, rather than create big buckets by OS or platform, so that it is clear to all exactly which product is being discussed rather than having to filter through unrelated cruft.