# Is [API] a meta tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I saw that there were many questions tagged with [api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) (more than 100 at the moment).

I feel that for most of these questions, this is sort of a meta tag, and could be replaced by a tag for a specific API.

There are a few questions where this tags make sense, but most of those are 'shopping' question, asking

> What API can I use to do X?

and these types of questions aren't exactly on-topic either.

Does the community feel that this tag is useful?

Comment: I think that there is just enough consensus in this Q&A to commence the burnination of the [tag:api] tag.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that this tag has no to little use and thus should not be used.

Perhaps when [A real solution to ambiguous tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags) is implemented that could be a solution that enables it to become more useful as a "gateway" tag.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use ambigus term. Person who search api know a name of api. For me the `api` alone term don't make sense because it's always used in the second term.

I think these examples are the good practice:

- dev. language with non specific api: `vb6-api`
- Arcgis software with non specific api: `arcgis-api`
- Arcgis software with Silverlight api: `arcgis-silverlight-api` if it's specific api subject

Note: Don't use the company name but the name of the product or language.

This topic can help you [Should we merge esri-silverlight and arcgis-silverlight-api tags into arcgis-silverlight?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3320/should-we-merge-esri-silverlight-and-arcgis-silverlight-api-tags-into-arcgis-sil) and others in meta.gis.stackexchange.